# JS Replace each HEX color with a new random HEX color

Tags: javascript, regex

Recently I've asked on how to replace a thousand of #FFF with a random HEX color.
The solution was to run this code:

```
var fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('stars.css', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  var result = data.replace(/#FFF/g, () => '#' + ("000000" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 8).toUpperCase()).slice(-6));

  fs.writeFile('stars.css', result, 'utf8', function (err) {
     if (err) return console.log(err);
  });
});
```

I'm looking for a way to detect any HEX color within the file, and replace it with a new random HEX color.
Here's what I tried:

```
var result = data.replace(/^#[0-9A-F]{6}$/i.test('#AABBCC'), () => '#' + ("000000" + Math.random().toString(16).slice>
```

Also, `("000000" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 8).toUpperCase()).slice(-6)` is the only way for me to get HEX color, as `Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)` method throws an  error on my webpage

Comment: Did you try and remove the `.test()` and just use: `.replace(/^#[0-9A-F]{6}$/ig, () => ...)`

Comment: Yep, didn't work

Comment: Try removing the `^` and `$` and use `Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)` to get a new hex

Comment: Didn't work + that method of getting HEX color doesn't work for me, still can't figure out why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `data.replace(/^#[0-9A-F]{6}$/i.test('#AABBCC'), () => '#' + ("000000" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 8).toUpperCase()).slice(-6));` with:

```js
data.replace(/#[0-9A-F]{3,6}/ig, () => `#${Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)}`);
```

I added `global` flag to your regex and found a shorter way to generate a random color from [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/random-hex-color/), besides removing unnecessary `.test` and deleting `^`/`$` (matches at the start of the string)

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work

Also, before I settled for the original way of getting a random hex, I tried the method you provided, which unfortunately brought errors to my html page

Comment: Tried
`var result = data.replace(/#[0-9A-F]{6}/ig, () => '#' + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16));`

Oddly only worked for the first hex in the file

Comment: I am not sure to understand, how did you get these errors if `replace` doesn't work? The regex should be working from my latest edit, sorry abouth that

Comment: `data.replace(/#[0-9A-F]{6}/ig, Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16));` managed to replace all HEX colors on a single random one

Comment: Do you need to replace with different random colors? Would you mind editing your question so the requirements are more clear?

Comment: For some reason, `Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)` method of getting a random HEX color throws me an error in my browser. Perhaps it doesn't give accurate HEX colors

Comment: Updated version still only replaces the first HEX, ignoring everything else inside the file

Comment: If you are using short hex like `#FFF`, change `#[0-9A-F]{6}` to `#[0-9A-F]{3,6}`

Comment: Yeah, just realized my mistake. Now it works like butter.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my function to generate a random HEX color :

```
function randomHEX(){
    const hex = (Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
    return `#${hex}`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Generate random [hex color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#Hex_triplet):

```
function rndHex(){return'#'+('00000'+(Math.random()*(1<<24)|0).toString(16)).slice(-6)}
```